# My logical is wrong somehow

Tags: c#

This should be simple, but somehow it is not. The messagebox displays zero's for both product quantity and product total price. Not quite sure why. Here is the code thus far:

Product Page

```
//will add the qty of the tshirts to the shop page. will catch non-integers
protected void linkTShirtAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int intOutput = 0;
    lblTShirtWarning.Visible = false;

    //determine that the value is parsable - if it is, assign values. Else, display error
    if (int.TryParse(txtTShirtQty.Text, out intOutput))
    {
        ProductClass.productName = "T-Shirt";
        ProductClass.productPrice = 10;
        ProductClass.productQty = Int16.Parse(txtTShirtQty.Text);
        //price of tshirts
        int totalTShirtPrice = ProductClass.productPrice * ProductClass.productQty;
        //display summary of the order
        MessageBox.Show (new Form {TopMost = true},
            "ORDER REVIEW" + "\n_______________________\n"
            + ProductClass.productName + "\n" 
            + "Quantity: " + ProductClass.productQty +"\n" 
            + "Total Price: " + totalTShirtPrice);
        //Response.Redirect("./Shop.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        lblTShirtWarning.Visible = true;
        lblTShirtWarning.Text = "Please enter a valid number";
        txtTShirtQty.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Product Class (to store the values)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for ProductClass
/// </summary>
public static class ProductClass
{

//obvious variables
private static String product;
private static int price;
private static int quantity;

//get and set the name of the product
public static String productName
{
    get
    {
        return product;
    }
    set
    {
        product = value;
    }
}

//get and set the price of the product
public static int productPrice
{
    get
    {
        return price;
    }
    set
    {
        price = value;
    }
}

//get and set the quantity of the product
public static int productQty
{
    get
    {
        return quantity;
    }
    set
    {
        price = value;
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Whats the value of `txtTShirtQty.Text`? And what is ``ProductClass`? Are your properties properly setup for both `get` and `set`?

Comment: At a guess, it'll be because `txtTShirtQty.Text` contains `0`.

Comment: The quantity of  txtTshirtQty.Text is user input. I'll add the ProductClass.

Comment: As an aside, why do you use `Int16.Parse`? **1.** `ProductCode.productQty` is declared as `int`, not as `short`; so `int.Parse` would be the more logical choice. **2.** You've already done the parsing once: just use the value of `intOutput` instead of parsing a second time.

Comment: I will look at this closer. It would not parse any other way. I used the Int16 because I knew the number would not be large. I forgot I could declare it as a short

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The getter and setter of `ProductCode.productQty` use different backing fields:

```
 public static int productQty
 {
     get
     {
         return quantity;
     }
     set
     {
         price = value;
     }
 }
```

Obviously, in the setter, `price = value;` is wrong, you probably meant `quantity = value;`.

Comment: That was it. Thank you - just took a second set of eyes